# Find the Maximum LatLng in a pool of LatLngs

Tags: javascript

I am in a situation where I need to find the maximum LatLng in a pool of LatLngs.

For example:
Imagine I have the following

```
LatLng(3.9,3.4);
LatLng(1.2,3.3);
LatLng(0.4,2.4);
```

Clearly from the above, I think the first `LatLng` pair is the farthest and biggest, but how can I determine this algorithmically is the problem I have.

For example, in a regular array of integers say `let a = [1,3,5,6]`;

```
let max = Math.max(a); //This would be 6.
```

But how can this be determined when working with pairs instead.

Any insight would be really appreciated.

Comment: where is your input and expected output?

Comment: would it not just be the max average between the lat/long pairs?

Comment: @m_callens I'm not sure I get that. I doubt that will work.

Comment: how do you define "maximum LatLng in the pool"

Comment: I've updated my question so you understand it better.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by 'max' – 'farthest and biggest' is a little vague.

Comment: @pilchard By farthest I meant the LatLng in the List that is farthest from a reference LatLng. Thank you.

Comment: Then you need to add that to the question. Sounds like you are looking to determine distance from one point to another on a sphere then. see: [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)